# Build number Format in TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, build

I want to include the version number of a specific assembly in my Build defintion number format, for example, instead of having the default [$(BuildDefinitionName)*$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)] i want to have something like [$(BuildDefinitionName)*$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)_Major.Minor.Build.Revision]

Is it possible? are the macros customizable?

Comment: Are you looking to pull the _Major.Minor.Build.Revision from someplace or put them in there manually?

Comment: no not manually, pull them from the built assembly.

Comment: note that usually the build number is decided by the build process and not pulled from any AssembyInfo.cs - rather overwritten, since usually the requirement is to have build numbers automated (and unique!)

Answer (score 4):

Try [Creating A New Build Number Generation Scheme](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willbar/archive/2010/01/21/generating-custom-build-number-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx).  I believe this is what you are looking for.

If you are still using a .proj due to an upgrade template all you do is create a custom task that inherits from Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Task and you can set that information there.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Mike, I know this answer applies to XAML builds, is there a way to do that in the new build definitions (TFS 2015/2017) as well? I've seen there are some [build variables available](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables), like the build definition name, but for the date I found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The macros are not customizable.  Microsoft provides a limited number of [Build Number tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh190719%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that can be replaced in the Update Build Number activity.